# Intel HD Graphics 4000 for Adobe CS5.5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, hardware-recommendation

I'm a graphic designer on a terribly limited budget and need a new laptop. I've been looking at the Acer Aspire V5-471 laptop, which has:

```
4GB RAM,
Intel Core i5-3337u CPU @ 1.8GHz (4 CPUs), ~1.8GHz
Intel HD Graphics 4000
```

Has anyone ever tried the Intel HD Graphics 4000 on CS5-CS6, with emphasis on Photoshop, Illustrator and InDesign? How has it performed?

Comments welcome.

Comment: I've downloaded Photoshop trial version. I've been using it and having no problems so far..

Answer (score 2):

CS5 and CS6 both should work completely fine on your laptop, doesn't matter if you want to use Ps, Ai, or ID. Check this link, Intel HD 4000 is on the Adobe approved list.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-cs6-gpu-faq.html